# Como justificar un texto con XML

Tags: android-studio, xml

Estoy intentando justificar un texto con unos dots en XML, lo he intentado de varias formas sin éxito alguno.

---

Ejemplo:

- Necesito  que el  texto sea  largo,  ya que debo  de poner varios puntos, detallando  cada  información  en un dot diferente.
- También debe de quedar justificado de esta manera, tal cual está en este ejemplo, pero la verdad es que queda de la siguiente forma.

(esto debe de quedar justificado)

Y esta quedando asi:

•   También debe de quedar justificado de esta manera, tal cual está en este ejemplo, pero la verdad es que queda de la siguiente forma.

• Necesito que el texto sea largo, ya que debo de poner varios puntos, detallando cada información en un dot diferente.

Mi string esta de la siguiente manera:

```
<string name="myString">\u25CF También debe de quedar justificado de esta manera, tal cual está en este ejemplo, pero la verdad es que queda de la siguiente forma.\n\n\u25CF También debe de quedar justificado de esta manera, tal cual está en este ejemplo, pero la verdad es que queda de la siguiente forma.\n\n\</string>
```

Comment: Hola ....., te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, , saludos!

Answer (score -1):

Existen varias librerías para eso:

navabi/JustifiedTextView https://github.com/navabi/JustifiedTextView

ufo22940268/android-justifiedtextview  https://github.com/ufo22940268/android-justifiedtextview

Apartir de Android O existe la justificación:

```
textView.setJustificationMode(JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD);
```

Comment: Hola que tal, muchas gracias por contestar. Este ya lo intente y no me funciona, y segun tengo entendido solo aplica para Android O. Y con Respecto a las librerias, no las puedo ocupar, ya que es un proyecto banario, donde las librerias deben de ser las autorizadas.